# Auto submit form with file upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I am writing a specific form-filler by hosting IE in my own app. I need to be able to upload files on certain forms by "auto-selecting" some files when `<input type="file" />` is encountered. As I have full control over HTML, I do not need to explicitly specify a file path as I am aware `value` property cannot be set for security reasons. I have no control over the server side.

Considering I can read the file contents myself, I may just as well feed the actual content to `<input>` element, but I am not sure this is supported.

I tried altering HTML so that `<input type="file" />` is replaced by a `<input type="hidden" value="QWERTY" />` but the form is not uploaded correctly. I suspect this is because file uploads and hidden form data are not transmitted exactly the same way.

So, is there a way to auto submit some content where a file upload is requested? I can take any solution, including direct HTML fiddling, javascript, jquery, etc...

Answer (score 2):

Maybe add an 'onChange' event handler to submit the form?

```
<form id="form">
    <input type="file" id="finput"/>
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#finput").on(change, function() { $("#form").submit(); });
```

Comment: Thanks, but how does this help exactly? I want to upload some specific file. I know how to submit a form.

Comment: @wpfwannabe Could you be more specific? Maybe supply a use case?

Comment: I have re-read my question and I am not sure what else to add. My problem is really simple. Consider any site that has a form with file upload. My app is embedding IE browser thus having a lot of control. As I want to auto-submit such form I want to upload file contents just as if the user selected "browse" and hit "upload/submit". So the question is... How do I submit this form by pre-selecting e.g. c:\test.txt for the file upload?

Comment: @wpfwannabe Hate to disappoint you but that's impossible for security reasons. File uploads can be submitted by JavaScript and if selecting files was possbile, sites could rip files right of clients.

Comment: Hm... I know about that part and I agree it is a security risk and is rightfully disallowed. But perhaps you are missing my point. I have full browser control on the client side (think desktop form auto-submitter). It is not like I want to steal files from whoever visits my site. I am not hosting a site. My aim is to have a desktop application (that hosts a browser) for the purpose of auto-submitting certain forms on certain sites. I hope that clears it up.